# How do you parse a SOQL AggregateResult column with no value?

Tags: salesforce, soql

Let's say you run a [SOQL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) aggregate query that looks like this:

```
select OwnerId, sum(ExpectedRevenue)val from Opportunity GROUP BY ROLLUP(OwnerId)
```

For whatever reason, there are no Opportunities with ExpectedRevenue fields populated.

You get a table that looks like this:

> > val___|OwnerId
> >
> > ```
> >      |Id1
> >      |Id2
> >      |Id3
> > ```
> >
> > 4/4 records.

(sidenote: how do you put in tabular data without it looking terrible?)

Take note that the "val" columns are all null and the last OwnerId column is also null.

There are 4 rows because SOQL returns a "total" row as well on rollups.

While looping through the AggregateResult[] that gets returned the code blows up on a line that looks like this: AggregateResult[0].get('val'); with a "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object"

However, if just 1 of those users has some data, then the whole thing works. So I'm guessing that if no rows have any data in a particular column, that column does not exist at all and calls to retrieve it blow up.

So my question is how do you determine if a column exists to avoid the null reference error?

Answer (score 1):

You have said that the ownerid column and the val columns are all null, therefore AggregateResult[0] is a pointer to a null object and any attempt to get a alue from that object give you the error you are having.

What I expect you want to be doing is before you run

```
AggregateResult[0].get('val');
```

you want to have an if statement say

```
if(AggregateResult.size() > 0)
```

or possibly

```
if(AggregateResult[0] != null)
```

to ensure that you are not attempting to access an empty object.

Try that and it should work. Otherwise post up a bigger code listing to look through.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

If there is no data to summarize for the filters you specify in your `where` clause you'll get an empty list of `AggregateResult` back.  You can test for this using list `isEmpty()` in Apex.